# Any method to detect which folders in C:\Users I can't access

Tags: c#, windows

I make a program in Windows 10 to collect all file list in my disk, and it should be run in system privilege.

But for personal folder, e.g. login as other user's account, I think I should avoid scanning their folders.

The user's personal folder is unser C:\Users usually. But how to detect which folder I can access? Or which one I cann't?

Below is my C:\Users folder and I can access all those folders. But if a new guy login on my Windows and create a new account, e.g. jack2. Then a new folder named jack2 should be shown there and I should not show any file in the C:\Users\jack2 when I run the program.

[image]

Comment: Why do you run the program with system privileges if you don't need them?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.username?view=net-6.0

Comment: To collect filst list of whole system, I need to use usn mechanism, which needs to be run under system priovilege.  @PMF

Comment: I know this api, but you remind me to just scan current user's directory. That's a good idea. Thanks! @HansPassant